# Using fancyref in TeX Live 2019 fails with undefined control sequence

Tags: errors, bugs, texlive-2019, fancyref

The following code worked well for me in TeX Live prior to 2019:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\title{TEST}

\usepackage{fancyref}

\begin{document}

\section{Actor}\label{sec:actor}

See \fref{sec:actor}

\end{document}
```

But since the update to TeX Live 2019 I receive the following error when trying to build the document:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./org.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 1
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/08/27 v1.4j Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fancyref/fancyref.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/varioref.sty))
No file org.aux.

LaTeX Warning: Reference `sec:actor' on page 1 undefined on input line 11.

! Undefined control sequence.
\@@vpageref ...@vrefhandlespace \vref@maybe@space 
                                                  \else \ifdim \@tempskipa =...
l.11 See \fref{sec:actor}
```

To make sure it worked prior to the upgrade, I asked a coworker to build it on his TeX Live 2018 installation and it worked fine. I am not certain if it is me misusing the `fancyref` package or if it is a bug in TeX Live.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could also use `cleveref` instead. It's a much newer package and has a whole bunch of better features (for instance, you don't need to use the `sec:` prefix).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`varioref` was recently updated and this `\vref@maybe@space` macro was added. `\vref@maybe@space` is defined when the command `\vpageref` is called. However `fancyref` uses some internal `varioref` macros directly, then `\vref@maybe@space` is never defined and you get that error.

Since `fancyref` uses `varioref`'s internals it should probably be updated to take the changes into account. Meanwhile you can use this patch after loading `fancyref`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@fancyref@page@ref}{%
  \let\vref@maybe@space\@empty % <-- Define \vref@maybe@space
  \@ifnextchar[%]
  \@vpageref{\@vpageref[\unskip]}}%
\makeatother
```

Comment: Should be fixed in upcoming LaTeX patch release. It is really more a fancyref issue, but it doesn't hurt to do some defencive programming here.